# How to plot a line over html text

Tags: html

I want to visually connect two words on an html page with a line. How do I accomplish that?

In an ideal scenario, I could hover over or click on a word in the text and another word lights up/changes background/gets connected by a line. The pairs of words could be stored in a table on the server side. Or it could just be the next occurrence of the same word, for the exercises sake.

Comment: @randy: Elaborate please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery (or plain JS, but JQuery makes this easy) to animate your wishes.

In this example, if you hover over the `u` tag, the `i` tag is getting underlined. For more effects, try some CSS rules that you fancy like shadow-box etc.

To make a connecting line between words is not going to be this easy. Try to understand what is happening here first, learn javascript (I enjoy YouTube for that) and shaka!

Next time, if you ask a question like this, we expect a little research effort though, that is the reason I did not answer yet. Good luck with this!

```js
$('u').on('mouseenter', function(){
  $('i').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
});

$('u').on('mouseleave', function(){
  $('i').css('text-decoration', 'none');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Hover over <u>this</u> word to highlight <i>this</i> word </p>
```

If you want to run this in your browser on your machine, create a file called `index.html` and put this in there:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>JQuery example</title>
</head>
<body>

    <p> Hover over <u>this</u> word to highlight <i>this</i> word </p>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $('u').on('mouseenter', function(){
        $('i').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
      });

      $('u').on('mouseleave', function(){
        $('i').css('text-decoration', 'none');
      });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using jQuery's `hide()` and `show()` methods.

You need to have an image of a line which you can hide using `hide()` at page load.

Then you need to have 2 words(2 text elements). So, when you click 1st word/element, you need to call `show()` method to show the hidden image which connects you to the other element.

You can also use jQuery Animation effects on the line. :)